# Using Java 8 Stream and Lambda I want to form a specific list from a list of list. Detail is given below

Tags: lambda, grouping, java-stream

Suppose I have a list of list like;

```
{
   {1-a12-abc,firstname,john},
   {2-a12-abc,firstname,tom},
   {1-a12-abc,lastname,doe},
   {3-a22-abc,city,Delhi}
}
```

We can think each list is containing some `PersonId`, `Attribute`, and `attribute value`. I want with each `Id`, the attribute list and corresponding value list together.

Using Java 8 Stream API I want a output like below:

```
    {
        {{1-a12-abc},{firstname,lastname},{john,doe}},
        {{2-a12-abc},{firstname},{tom}},
        {{3-a22-abc},{city},{Delhi}}
    }
```

Where grouping will be with the first element of each list as given above. The second and third elements for each group will form list.

Please help with the solution.

Comment: Look at `Stream.map()`, `Stream.collect()`, `Collectors.groupingBy()`. When you get stuck you can come back and ask with more detail. But do not expect someone to give you a complete solution without showing any own effort.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a version using java 8 streams:

```
// Initial list
public class AttributeValue {
    String id;
    String attribute;
    String attributeValue;

    AttributeValue(String id, String attribute, String attributeValue) {
        this.id = id;
        this.attribute = attribute;
        this.attributeValue = attributeValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + id + "," + attribute + "," + attributeValue + "}";
    }

    // ommiting equals() and hashCodes() methods for simplification
}

// final list
public class Record {
    String id;
    List<String> attributes;
    List<String> attributeValues;

    Record(String id, List<String> attributes, List<String> attributeValues) {
        this.id = id;
        this.attributes = attributes;
        this.attributeValues = attributeValues;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{{" + id + "},"
                + attributes.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",", "{", "}")) + ","
                + attributeValues.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",", "{", "}")) + "}";
    }

    // ommiting equals() and hashCodes() methods for simplification
}

private List<Record> transform(List<AttributeValue> values) {
    return values.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(value -> value.id, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(pair -> new Record(
                pair.getKey(),
                pair.getValue().stream().map(value -> value.attribute).collect(Collectors.toList()),
                pair.getValue().stream().map(value -> value.attributeValue).collect(Collectors.toList())
            ))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And the unit tests using junit5 and assertj for fluency:

```
@Test
void parse_a_van_page_with_empty_json_data() throws Exception {
    List<AttributeValue> initial = Arrays.asList(
            new AttributeValue("1-a12-abc", "firstname", "john"),
            new AttributeValue("2-a12-abc", "firstname", "tom"),
            new AttributeValue("1-a12-abc", "lastname", "doe"),
            new AttributeValue("3-a22-abc", "city", "Delhi")
    );

    List<Record> expected = Arrays.asList(
            new Record("1-a12-abc", Arrays.asList("firstname", "lastname"), Arrays.asList("john", "doe")),
            new Record("2-a12-abc", Collections.singletonList("firstname"), Collections.singletonList("tom")),
            new Record("3-a22-abc", Collections.singletonList("city"), Collections.singletonList("Delhi"))
    );

    assertThat(transform(initial)).containsAll(expected);

    // Some printing
    System.out.println("initial: ");
    initial.forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("expected: ");
    expected.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```